# "As you wish" - "Up to you", are both polite?

Tags: word-usage

> As you wish.
>
> Up to you.

Which one is the more polite expression?

Answer (score 1):

[as you wish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-you-wish-like) indicates that the other person has already made a choice and you accept it, but you do not agree with it.

[it's up to you](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100416075626AANBUqQ) Indicates that no decision have been made, and you think that the other person should make the decision.

Both are polite, but "as you wish" definitely conveys disapproval.

Comment: Unless "as you wish" is said by Westley to Princess Buttercup.

Comment: @mkennedy, Ihad to look that one up :-)

Comment: Oh, and so I just learned that _as you wish_  and  _up to you_ do not have the same tendency :)